# undefined method rails 3.2.9 and devise 1.0.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Error:
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.0.11/lib/devise.rb:89:in '':   undefined method 'weeks' for 2:Fixnum (NoMethodError)

That error is thrown whenever I try to run 'rails g devise:install' in a rails project I've been working on.

Any ideas?

P.S. requiring gem 'devise' in Gemfile and running bundle install to get the devise gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was already dealt with [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/184).  Try updating to a later devise version to fix.